# What’s a proper way to wire a dishwasher

Tags: electrical, wiring, dishwasher

I am in the process of wiring for a second dishwasher. The first one is hardwired and has a wall switch.

My thought is to put the old work outlets for both dishwashers inside the wall (it’s a wood frame exterior wall) fish the wires from under the floor, and do away with the wall switch for the original dw for consistency. I will attach appliance plugs to both dishwashers. Is this a good plan? Photos of both locations attached. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear why you would use a wall switch on a dishwasher.

Comment: I prefer hardwired. Most dishwashers can be hardwired or cord/plug - check the installation manual. Also check with your local code - you *may* not have any GFCI requirement **or** only if plug/cord **or** always - depending on whether you have GFCI already in the panel, that may make the difference as to what to do. But keep in mind that a GFCI needs to be accessible for reset. Should be no need for a switch for a dishwasher. Only time I've seen one is my parents had one put in when they got a 2nd dishwasher because the *plumbing* couldn't handle both running at the same time.

Comment: @jwh20. I’m not going to. Existing one has one and I tbi k it was required for hardwired dishwashers (not sure). Thus I’m planning to do away with switch and have simple outlets for both.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact So the breaker is a standard 20A. Unless the wall switch is somehow GFCI protected (can't see how as there is no reset), then I don't think it is GFCI protected at all. So I'm thinking to terminate both lines with GFCI outlets in the wall and then plug the dishwashers with appliance cords. What is the reason you like them hardwired? Any real advantages? I prefer the neatness of properly terminated wires personally.

Comment: With hardwired, all the wiring can be totally hidden - or at most a small bit coming out into a junction box in the next cabinet. With plug/cord, there is more "stuff". However, GFCI can make the difference. Keep in mind that you can't have them go to the *same* 20A circuit - you either need two separate circuits or an MWBC - but neither one will work a normal GFCI/receptacle - in other words, two separate GFCI/duplex-receptacle devices.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes, the second photo shows another dedicated 12g 20A circuit for the second DW. As far as more stuff, I mean everything will be inside the wall and terminated in a regular wall outlet, flush with the wall if that makes sense. I'll just cut out the bottom of the drywall, drill a hole in the bottom plate and feed it up to an old work box with a GFCI, maybe a foot above the floor. Does that sound good?

Comment: It does make sense. I guess I just prefer hardwired for something that is *never* unplugged (except when being replaced, or when being service but for those rare times you can just flip the breaker).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Understood. I have old (red reset) GFCIs laying around (putting white ones in reno kitchen), so was thinking by installing those as outlets will kill two birds (having GFCI), with one stone.

Comment: Better time to install new dishwashers is right before Passover (I did that, along with the rest of the kitchen. I was crazy. (Still am.)). But new dishwashers for a new year works too.

Comment: Is that a burn mark in the first photo?  Might want to hunt that down.

Answer (score 3):

Ok the GFCI would need to be accessible I usually put them in the cabinet between the sink and dishwasher. (My state did not adopt GFCI for dishwasher so if the customer wants them that’s where I locate them). Romex as the connection is not the correct method. A metal clad or flexible conduit to protect the wiring is the code compliant hard wire method. The Romex can get pinched moving the unit so the Romex stops at the old work box then metal clad to the junction box on the dishwasher. Yes almost everyone has a dishwasher wired this way but an inspector will red tag this. I have been called several times to change wiring like this. Since the dishwashers are fixed in place the max load of 50% of the branch circuit rating. Per NEC 210.23.A.2 so normally a dishwasher gets a dedicated circuit.

Comment: The houses  I lived in built around 2002, all had Romex hardwired. Must be a new code change. Is pulling out dishwasher to expose GFCI considered accessible? I could just put a regular outlet and GFCI at the breaker box, rather than put so many outlets under the sink cabinet. That cabinet will also have garbage disposal and its switch.

Comment: If the inspector looks it will be flagged Romex is not rated for flex and never has been. The times I have been called mostly have been when the dishwasher is removed and the inspector catches the romex. As I said yes almost everyone has a house wired like this but it is below the code standard for hard wire because Romex is not rated for flex. No the GFCI must be accessible without moving the unit because it is fixed. They do make dead face GFCI’s that I have put in cabinet faces or put the receptacle where the switch is so it can be reset.

Comment: So GFCI at the breaker no good?

Comment: GFCI at breaker is fine - that's accessible.

Comment: Metal clad or flexible conduit is a must.  I was working on a dishwasher that was hard wired and as I slid it out from under the counter top...POP!  The wire was not protected and the sheet metal sliced right through the insulation.